# Deserializing into a List without a container element in XML

Tags: c#, .net, xml-serialization

In all the examples I've seen of using `XmlSerializer` any time a list or array happens you have some sort of container element like this:

```xml
<MyXml>
  <Things>
    <Thing>One</Thing>  
    <Thing>Two</Thing>  
    <Thing>Three</Thing>  
  </Things>
</MyXml>
```

However, the XML I have has no container similar to *Things* above. It just starts repeating elements. (Incidentally, the XML is actually from Google's Geocode API)

So, I have XML that looks like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<GeocodeResponse>
  <status>OK</status>
  <result>
    <type>locality</type>
    <type>political</type>
    <formatted_address>Glasgow, City of Glasgow, UK</formatted_address>
    <address_component>
      <long_name>Glasgow</long_name>
      <short_name>Glasgow</short_name>
      <type>locality</type>
      <type>political</type>
    </address_component>
    <address_component>
      <long_name>East Dunbartonshire</long_name>
      <short_name>East Dunbartonshire</short_name>
      <type>administrative_area_level_3</type>
      <type>political</type>
    </address_component>
    <!-- etc... -->
  </result>
  <result>
    <!-- etc... -->
  </result>
  <result>
    <!-- etc... -->
  </result>
</GeocodeResponse>
```

As you can see inside *result* the *type* element repeats without any *types* element that *XmlSerializer* appears to expect (or at least all the documents and examples I've seen). The same goes for the *address_component*.

The code I currently have looks something like this:

```
[XmlRoot("GeocodeResponse")]
public class GeocodeResponse
{
    public GeocodeResponse()
    {
        this.Results = new List<Result>();
    }

    [XmlElement("status")]
    public string Status { get; set; }

    [XmlArray("result")]
    [XmlArrayItem("result", typeof(Result))]
    public List<Result> Results { get; set; }
}
```

Every time I attempt to *deserialize* the XML I get zero items in my *Result* *List*.

Can you suggest how I may get this to work as I'm currently not seeing it?

Comment: FYI: this exact question was posted to SO, yesterday.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5259911/deserialize-multiple-xml-elements-with-the-same-name-through-xmlserializer-class  There is one intervening Q between that one and this one, under the xml-serialization tag. Also, it's not the first time it's been asked/answered.

Comment: Well, I couldn't find it! I searched first, and clicked through all the the suggestions when I put in my question title.

Answer (score 107, accepted):

Use

```
[XmlElement("result")]
public List<Result> Results { get; set; }
```

Comment: It worked - I cannot believe it was that stupidly simple that I missed it. Doh!

Comment: I have attempted to use this, and for some reason it is only grabbing the first in the list of items. I'm not sure why, and it's getting really aggravating.

Comment: We are facing the same situation of repeating XML elements without container, however we are using the DataContract serializer (a WCF service) and, have not found a solution for deserializing the repeating XML elements without container into a list; the list property ends up with zero elements. Is there a similar solution to deserialize repeating XML elements without container in this case? [DataMember(IsRequired = false, Order = 3)] public List<RequestorIdentification> Identifications { get; set; }

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, I couldn't find a solution, so I'll post my solution.

Problem:

There is xml without a container (this xml is not valid, it is an internal part, unfortunately there is no way to change its format)

```
<Item number="3"></Item>
<Item number="4"></Item>
```

We only know the type to deserialize to (IEnumarable).
Here is the method I wrote for deserialization.

```
[XmlRoot(nameof(Items))]
public class EnumerableWrapper<T>
{
    public T Items { get; set; }
}

private static object? GetValueFromEnumerableType(List<XElement> xmlElements, Type enumerableType)
{
    if (!xmlElements.Any()) return null;

    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    var type = typeof(EnumerableWrapper<>).MakeGenericType(enumerableType);

    sb.AppendLine($"<{nameof(EnumerableWrapper<object>.Items)}>");
    foreach (var xmlProp in xmlElements)
        sb.AppendLine(xmlProp.ToString());
    sb.AppendLine($"</{nameof(EnumerableWrapper<object>.Items)}>");

    using var arrayXmlReader = new StringReader(sb.ToString());

    var overrides = new XmlAttributeOverrides();
    overrides.Add(type, nameof(EnumerableWrapper<object>.Items), new XmlAttributes()
    {
        XmlElements =
        {
            new XmlElementAttribute()
            {
                ElementName = xmlElements[0].Name.LocalName,
            }
        }
    });

    var serializer = new XmlSerializer(type, overrides);

    var result = serializer.Deserialize(arrayXmlReader);
    return result is null
        ? null
        : type.GetProperty(nameof(EnumerableWrapper<object>.Items))!.GetValue(result, null);
}

private static object? GetValueFromEnumerableType<T>(List<XElement> xmlElements)
    => GetValueFromEnumerableType(xmlElements, typeof(T));
```