# Deserializing XML returns null for collection property

Tags: c#, xml, deserialization, xmlserializer

I'm trying to deserialize the following XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<mf:somedata xmlns:mf="urn:somedata">
    <CurrentAccount>
        <AccountType>test</AccountType>
        <Charge>
            <ChargeType>test</ChargeType>
        </Charge>
    </CurrentAccount>
    <CurrentAccount>
        <AccountType>test 2</AccountType>
        <Charge>
            <ChargeType>test 2</ChargeType>
        </Charge>
    </CurrentAccount>
</mf:somedata>
```

Using the following classes:

```
[XmlRoot("somedata", Namespace = "urn:somedata")]
public class MfCurrentAccounts
{
    [XmlElement("CurrentAccount")]
    public CurrentAccount[] CurrentAccounts { get; set; }
}

public class CurrentAccount
{
    public string AccountType { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("Charge")]
    public Charge[] Charges { get; set; }
}

public class Charge
{
    public string ChargeType { get; set; }
}

var c = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MfCurrentAccounts)).Deserialize(new StringReader(xml)) as MfCurrentAccounts;

c.CurrentAccounts // <-- is always null
```

But no matter what I try, the CurrentAccounts array is null when I deserialize it. I've tried every combination I can think of with the attributes (I've tried XmlArray and XmlArrayItem too).

What am I doing wrong? :S

Comment: Sorry, updated the question with the deserialization code.

Comment: Do you not need to mark the classes with `[Serializable()]`?

Comment: @François I have tried that, but apparently it's not needed.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Deserializing into a List without a container element in XML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5271442/deserializing-into-a-list-without-a-container-element-in-xml)

Comment: @Dan-o How can that be a duplicate when *this* code already does as that answer suggests? The only difference from the annotation/property with *this* code to the "duplicate answer" is that it uses an Array instead of a List.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is with Namespaces.

When I created that entire class setup in a test situation, i got a very different looking output.  here is what I think you should be trying to read in:

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <mf:somedata xmlns:mf="urn:somedata">
        <mf:CurrentAccount>
            <mf:AccountType>something 1</mf:AccountType>
            <mf:Charge>
                <mf:ChargeType>Charge Type 1</mf:ChargeType>
            </mf:Charge>
        </mf:CurrentAccount>
        <mf:CurrentAccount>
            <mf:AccountType>something 2</mf:AccountType>
            <mf:Charge>
                <mf:ChargeType>Charge Type 2</mf:ChargeType>
            </mf:Charge>
        </mf:CurrentAccount>
    </mf:somedata>
```

Notice all the extra `mf:`.  When you declare the namespace, the serializer will work with that and only de-serialize nodes that properly belong to that namespace.  You either need to get rid of it entirely or fix your input appropriately.  Here is the code that I used to generate that output *note: the class definitions are completely unchanged*

```
XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MfCurrentAccounts));
XmlSerializerNamespaces ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
ns.Add("mf", "urn:somedata");

MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
ser.Serialize(ms, a, ns);
```

and when reading it back in:

```
ms.Position = 0;
b = ser.Deserialize(ms) as MfCurrentAccounts;
```

after running both sections, b is now a perfect clone of a, and the xml I showed above is the generated xml.

Comment: Thanks for that. Unfortunately the XML is coming from a third party, so I have no control over it. I tried adding this to the CurrentAccounts property: `[XmlElement("CurrentAccount", Namespace = "urn:somedata")]` but to no avail.

Comment: Can you edit the xml before attempting to deserialize it?  If you use some Regex on that first line and eliminate the "mf:" from the top node, then you will have a uniform classdef and it should deserialize properly...

Comment: @Tom have you tried [XmlElement("CurrentAccount", Namespace = String.Empty)] ?

Comment: @jbl You saved another life Namespace = "", worked!!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try replacing your MfCurrentAccounts class with :

```
[XmlRoot("somedata", Namespace = "urn:somedata")]
public class MfCurrentAccounts : List<CurrentAccount>
{
   public MfCurrentAccounts():base()
   {}

}
```

or give a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/364410/1236044

Hope this will help

Comment: That just returns an empty list. :( I'll play around with it though, as it seems like it should work. I'll have a look at writing to disk and using an XSD file, but I'd rather not go down that route.

Comment: @Tom the class might need a public constructor. I updated my answer

Comment: That didn't seem to work either, but your comment on the previous answer works. :)