# DataContract serializer not deserializing into a list repeating XML elements without container element

Tags: c#, .net, deserialization, xml-deserialization, datacontractserializer

We are facing a situation where the `DataContract` serializer (a WCF service) is not deserializing repeating XML elements without container element into a list; the list property ends up with zero elements.

The datacontracts we have:

```
[DataContract]
public class Requestor
{
    [DataMember(IsRequired = true, Order = 0)]
    public string RequestorRole;

    [DataMember(IsRequired = true, Order = 1)]
    public string RequestorGivenName;

    [DataMember(IsRequired = true, Order = 2)]
    public string RequestorSurName;

    [DataMember(IsRequired = false, Order = 3)] 
    public List<RequestorIdentification> RequestorIdentification { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class RequestorIdentification
{
    [DataMember(IsRequired = true, Order = 0)]
    public string IdentificationID;

    [DataMember(IsRequired = true, Order = 1)]
    public string IdentificationCategoryCode;
}
```

The XML we want to deserialize:

```html
      <Requestor xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Serialization">
        <RequestorRole>Physicians</RequestorRole>
        <RequestorGivenName>Rich</RequestorGivenName>
        <RequestorSurName>Smith</RequestorSurName>
        <RequestorIdentification>
          <IdentificationID>AB1234567</IdentificationID>
          <IdentificationCategoryCode>DEA</IdentificationCategoryCode>
        </RequestorIdentification>
        <RequestorIdentification>
          <IdentificationID>0123456789</IdentificationID>
          <IdentificationCategoryCode>NPI</IdentificationCategoryCode>
        </RequestorIdentification>
  </Requestor>
```

How can we resolve the issue using the `DataContract` serializer?

So far we have found no way to make it work, and this page https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/collection-types-in-data-contracts was not of much help.

The same issue was resolved for the `XmlSerializer` in this question:

[Deserializing into a List without a container element in XML](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5271442/463478)

Answer (score 0):

To deserialize the XML shown in the OP, one can use [XmlElement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlelement?view=netframework-4.8). However, this requires the use of [XmlSerializer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer?view=netframework-4.8) instead of [DataContractSerializer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractserializer?view=netframework-4.8) for serialization and deserialization.

According to this [post](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/types-supported-by-the-data-contract-serializer#additional-notes-on-serialization)

> The DataContractSerializer does not support the programming model used
> by the XmlSerializer and ASP.NET Web services. In particular, it does
> not support attributes like XmlElementAttribute and
> XmlAttributeAttribute. To enable support for this programming model,
> WCF must be switched to use the XmlSerializer instead of the
> DataContractSerializer.

The code below shows how one can deserialize the XML shown in the OP.

**Create a Windows Forms App (.NET Framework)**

**Add Reference** (System.Runtime.Serialization)

**VS 2019**

- In VS menu, click **Project**
- Select **Add Reference...**
- Click **Assemblies**
- Check **System.Runtime.Serialization**
- Click **OK**

---

**The following using directives are used in the code below**:

- `using System;`
- `using System.Collections.Generic;`
- `using System.IO;`
- `using System.Runtime.Serialization;`
- `using System.Text;`
- `using System.Xml;`
- `using System.Xml.Serialization;`

**Create a class** (name: RequestorRequestorIdentification.cs)

```
[DataContract(Name = "RequestorIdentification")]
public class RequestorRequestorIdentification
{
    [DataMember]
    public string IdentificationID { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string IdentificationCategoryCode { get; set; }
}
```

**Create a class** (name: Requestor.cs)

```
[DataContract(Name ="Requestor")]
public class Requestor
{
    [DataMember]
    public string RequestorRole { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string RequestorGivenName { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string RequestorSurName { get; set; }

    [XmlElement]
    public List<RequestorRequestorIdentification> RequestorIdentification { get; set; } = new List<RequestorRequestorIdentification>();

}
```

**Note**: The use of [XmlElement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlelement?view=netframework-4.8) requires the use of [XmlSerializer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer?view=netframework-4.8) instead of [DataContractSerializer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractserializer?view=netframework-4.8) for serialization and deserialization.

**Create a class** (name: HelperXml.cs)

```
public class HelperXml
{
    public static T DeserializeXMLFileToObject<T>(string xmlFilename)
    {
        //usage: Requestor requestor = DeserializeXMLFileToObject<Requestor>(xmlFilename);

        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(xmlFilename))
            throw new Exception("Error: xmlFilename is null or empty.");

        return DeserializeXMLToObject<T>(File.ReadAllBytes(xmlFilename));
    }

    public static T DeserializeXMLToObject<T>(string xmlText)
    {
        //usage: Requestor requestor = DeserializeXMLToObject<Requestor>(xmlText);

        //create new instance
        using (System.IO.StringReader reader = new System.IO.StringReader(xmlText))
        {
            System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer serializer = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(T), "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Serialization");
            return (T)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
        }
    }

    public static T DeserializeXMLToObject<T>(byte[] xmlBytes)
    {
        //usage: Requestor requestor = DeserializeXMLToObject<Requestor>(File.ReadAllBytes(xmlFilename));

        //create new instance of MemoryStream
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(xmlBytes))
        {
            using (XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(ms))
            {
                System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer serializer = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(T), "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Serialization");
                return (T)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
            }
        }
    }
    public static void SerializeObjectToXMLFile(object obj, string xmlFilename)
    {
        //Usage: Class1 myClass1 = new Class1();
        //SerializeObjectToXMLFile(myClass1, xmlFilename);

        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(xmlFilename))
            throw new Exception("Error: xmlFilename is null or empty.");

        //Xml writer settings
        XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
        settings.OmitXmlDeclaration = true;
        settings.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
        settings.Indent = true;

        using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(xmlFilename, settings))
        {
            //specify namespaces
            System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializerNamespaces ns = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializerNamespaces();
            ns.Add(string.Empty, "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Serialization");

            //create new instance
            System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer serializer = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(obj.GetType(), "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Serialization");

            //write to XML file
            serializer.Serialize(writer, obj, ns);
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Usage** (deserialize):

```
private Requestor _requestor = null;
            ...

//deserialize
//_requestor = HelperXml.DeserializeXMLFileToObject<Requestor>(Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments), "Test.xml"));
//_requestor = HelperXml.DeserializeXMLToObject<Requestor>(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xmlText));
_requestor = HelperXml.DeserializeXMLToObject<Requestor>(xmlText);
```

**Usage** (serialize):

```
private Requestor _requestor = null;
            ...

//create new instance
_requestor = new Requestor();

_requestor.RequestorRole = "Physicians";
_requestor.RequestorGivenName = "Rich";
-requestor.RequestorSurName = "Smith";

_requestor.RequestorIdentification.Add(new RequestorRequestorIdentification() { IdentificationID = "AB1234567", IdentificationCategoryCode = "DEA" });
_requestor.RequestorIdentification.Add(new RequestorRequestorIdentification() { IdentificationID = "0123456789", IdentificationCategoryCode = "NPI" });

using (SaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog())
{
    sfd.Filter = "XML File (*.xml)|*.xml";
    sfd.FileName = "Test.xml";

    if (sfd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        HelperXml.SerializeObjectToXMLFile(_requestor, sfd.FileName);
        Debug.WriteLine($"Info: Saved to '{sfd.FileName}'");
    }
}
```

---

**Additional Resources**:

- [Types Supported by the Data Contract Serializer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/types-supported-by-the-data-contract-serializer)
- [DataContractAttribute Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractattribute?view=netframework-4.8)
- [Using Data Contracts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/using-data-contracts)
- [Using the XmlSerializer Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/using-the-xmlserializer-class)
- [Collection Types in Data Contracts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/collection-types-in-data-contracts)
- [Data Member Order](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/data-member-order)