# Assigning multiple xml node value to one class property in c#

Tags: xml, c#-4.0

Xml 1:

```
<Test><Anything>12345</Anything></Test>
```

Xml 2:

```
<Test><Anything1>test123</Anything1></Test>

Class Test
{
    [XmlElement("Anything" or "Anything" )]
    public string Sample { get; set; }
}
```

In my case any one of the xml will come. so i have to assign either Anything tag or Anything1 to Sample property.

is this possible?

Comment: I don't think you can or that you should. Because that is not really how to use XML.

Answer (score 0):

If the elements are in a fixed order, you can do it. See [Deserialize multiple XML elements with the same name through XmlSerializer class in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5259911/deserialize-multiple-xml-elements-with-the-same-name-through-xmlserializer-class) for more information.

Otherwise, you cannot do it. If you do:

```
public class Test
{
    [XmlElement("Anything")]
    [XmlElement("Foo")]
    public string Sample { get; set; }
}

...

Test test = new Test { Sample = "test" };
XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Test));
```

it throws an `InvalidOperationException` saying "There was an error reflecting type 'AntlrTest.Program.Test'". The problem is not necessary loading the type, it is writing it out.